# Mouse click rectangle doesn't update to actual mouse position

Tags: xna, c#, mouse

I'm making a menu in XNA; and to solve clunky input via arrow keys, I thought I would use mouse input. I got everything to work perfectly, then I tried to click on something specific and nothing happened. To troubleshoot, I drew an image where the cursor rectangle is supposed to be. As you can see in the image below it's nowhere near my mouse.

[One image of the cursors lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ong.png)

[Another image of the cursors lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxYnm.png)

Note how they are in two different places.

How do I fix this horrible lag?

The menu update calls a mouse class to update the mouse position and place it within bounds of the screen. The mouse class also has a rectangle that updates based on the mouse position, but it updates almost 200 pixels away. The mouse moves fine in game, it's just the rectangle is in a weird position

```
   //This is located in the Mouse Class
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        oldmouse = currentmouse;
        currentmouse = Mouse.GetState();
        Position.X = currentmouse.X;
        Position.Y = currentmouse.Y;
        //Some other boundary code that's not essential
        clickRectangle.X = (int)Position.X;
        clickRectangle.Y = (int)Position.Y;
    }

    // this is located in the menu class

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(ArrowTexture, mouseInput.clickRectangle, Color.White);
        //draw other arrows and text
    }
```

I don't see a problem with the code. Is there something else I have to do?

I should also mention it sometimes draw nearer to the actual cursor and sometimes farther away. The cursor only drew to my actual cursor once before it stopped working.

EDIT: I updated the question with more relevant information. I apologize for not including it earlier.

Comment: This part is fine. You're drawing it wrong, probably.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs The drawing was optional, and the lag occurs with or without me drawing the arrow.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but what's changed? Do a diff with the last rev that worked in your source control system. (You ARE using source control, aren't you? :))

Comment: @DavidLively   I unfortunately do not use source control :( if you know of a good one shoot me an email at: thegluestickmam(at)gmail(dot)com

I should also mention that the cursor will sometimes draw nearer to my mouse and sometimes farther away. It only worked once for me.

Comment: Beanstalk has free svn repos for closed source projects.

Comment: If you drag your game window to the top-left corner of the screen, does the problem disappear?

Comment: Sort of, if I move the game to the top left corner it moves to far the other way. But I did manage to get the rectangle in the right spot by moving the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, long after I figured out the problem.

Early in my menu development I inherited the "Game" class from XNA. I forget why, I think it had to do with getting certain method to work or something. I guess I had removed the code that need the inheritance and kept the inheritance which screwed up my update method. It wanted to override it but I didn't do that. Anyway I removed the inheritance and it worked fine.

Doi.